# SSN Regex with first digit up to '8'

Tags: c#, regex

I need to have a regex for a social security number (SSN), with a condition: the first digit should have a maximum value of 8.

The SSN format can be either 123-45-6789  or 123456789, i.e. it should validate either with an '-' symbol or without it.

This is what I tried so far, and it's not working

```
this.var rx = new Regex("^\[0-8][0-9][0-9]-?\\d{2}-?\\d{4}$");
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Yes. SO is not a free coding service

Comment: Eh, something like this `^[0-8](-?[0-9]+)+$`? The very first symbol is in the `[0..8]` range followed by groups of any digits (`[0..9]`), with optional `-` prefixes

Comment: hi folks,   I tried with something like this.var rx = new Regex("^\\[0-8][0-9][0-9]-?\\d{2}-?\\d{4}$");

Comment: But it did n't help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know regex with c# but I guess your `\` in the beginning breaks your regex.

try

```
^[0-8]\\d{2}-?\\d{2}-?\\d{4}$
```

In c# i guess you have to do `\\d`

see https://regex101.com/r/IfxQvr/1